# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__module__'

Tags: python, caching

I have been testing out this caching method/code:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245-lru-and-lfu-cache-decorators/?c=15348

and in some cases, I get this (or similar) error:
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '**module**'"

and here are code examples, these work fine:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
@lru_cacheItem(maxsize=20)
def f(x, y):
    return 3*x+y

domain = range(5)
from random import choice
for i in range(1000):
    r = f(choice(domain), choice(domain))

print('Hits:{0}'.format(f.hits), 'Misses:{0}'.format(f.misses))

@lfu_cacheItem(maxsize=20)
def f(x, y):
    return 3*x+y

domain = range(5)
from random import choice
for i in range(1000):
    r = f(choice(domain), choice(domain))

print('Hits:{0}'.format(f.hits), 'Misses:{0}'.format(f.misses))  


@lru_cacheItem(maxsize=20)
def myString(a, b):
    return '{0} and {1}'.format(a, b)

a = 'crap'
b = 'shit'
for i in range(1000):
    r = myString(a, b)

print('Hits:{0}'.format(myString.hits), 'Misses:{0}'.format(myString.misses))
```

and this does not:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
class P4client(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def checkFileStats(self, filePath):
        results = 'The filepath: {0}'.format(filePath)
        print results
        return results

p4client = P4client()

filePath = (r"C:\depot\tester.tga")

@lfu_cacheItem            
def p4checkFileStats(filePath):
    '''Will cache the fstats return'''
    p4checkResults = p4client.checkFileStats(filePath)
    return p4checkResults    

p4checkFileStats(filePath)
```

I am not sure how to fix this ... it appears to be an issue in functools, I assume somehow do to that fact I am calling a class/method within the function I am wrapping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@lfu_cacheItem            
def p4checkFileStats(filePath):
```

You are missing parenthesis here:

```
@lfu_cacheItem()            
def p4checkFileStats(filePath):
```

All decorators which expect "options", i.e. that you can use as:

```
@decorator(a=Something, b=Other, ...)
def the_function(...):
```

**Must** always be *called* when decorating, even if you do not provide arguments:

```
@decorator()
def the_function(...):
```

---

Why you wonder? Well, first of all remember that decorators are normal functions that accept a function as argument:

```
In [1]: def hooray(func):
   ...:     print("I'm decorating function: {.__name__}".format(func))
   ...:     return func

In [2]: @hooray
   ...: def my_function(): pass
I'm decorating function: my_function
```

As you can see `hooray` was *called*. In fact this is what really happens when using a decorator:

```
In [3]: def my_function(): pass
   ...: my_function = hooray(my_function)
   ...: 
I'm decorating function: my_function
```

Now, if you want to pass options to the decorator you can create a function that returns a *decorator*. This is exactly what happens with `lfu_cache` from the recipe you link:

```
def lfu_cache(maxsize=100):
    # ...
    def decorating_function(user_function):
        # ...
    return decorating_function
```

Now here you can see that `lfu_cache` is really a function. this function *creates* a decorator, called `decorating_function` and returns it. This means that when calling:

```
@lfu_cache(maxsize=20)
def my_function(): pass
```

This is what happens:

```
def my_function(): pass
decorator = lfu_cache(maxsize=20)
my_function = decorator(my_function)
```

As you can see first `lfu_cache` is called, and returns a decorator. Afterwards the decorator is called to decorate the function.
What happens if you forget the parenthesis? What does this:

```
@lfu_cache
def my_function(): pass
```

do?

Pretty simple, it uses `lfu_cache` as a simple decorator:

```
def my_function(): pass
my_function = lfu_cache(my_function)
```

But this is bad! You passed a function as `maxsize` parameter and the value returned by `lfu_cache` is the `decorating_function` of before!

to learn more about decorators read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python/1594484#1594484) So answer.